# install glassfish appclient?

Tags: software-installation, java, repository, webserver, application

I can recall [using](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaem.html) this syntax:

`appclient -client converterClient.jar`

to invoke the Glassfish appclient.  How would I install Glassfish through a repository so that this command is then available?

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ appclient -client NetBeansProjects/ejbClient/build/libs/ejbClient.jar 
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: running..
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App run
INFO: {java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
Nov 06, 2017 12:10:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App lookup
INFO: looking up jndi
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ alias appclient
alias appclient='/home/thufir/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/bin/appclient '
thufir@dur:~$
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144941/262852